# webpack 2, changing publicPath without generating whole new bundle

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I have a question maybe you can help me, I need to send my bundle to couple of storage accounts, the only thing Im changing is "publicPath: ${path}" is it a way to not make this change without make the whole bundle again? Its slowing down my deployment process a lot :<

Comment: Why are you changing it at all?

Comment: Have different cdn's

Comment: And different websites in different countries that are sharing the same js